# Similar function to scipy.stats.zscore but base on another "sample"

Tags: scipy, outliers

I have 2 datasets which describe the same process and I expect the same general range of values.  So I would like to do is use `scipy.stats.zscore` on the one dataset but instead of using the sample mean and standard deviation, I would like to use the mean and standard deviation from the other dataset.  Is there such an equivalent function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`scipy.stats.zmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zmap.html).

```
In [141]: import numpy as np

In [142]: from scipy.stats import zmap

In [143]: olddata = np.array([3.67, 4.01, 3.60, 5.36, 3.65, 2.01, 2.75, 4.43, 2.74, 3.89, 3.60])

In [144]: newdata = np.array([1.0, 2.4, 2.5, 3.25, 5.6])

In [145]: zmap(newdata, olddata)
Out[145]: array([-3.05378533, -1.41573956, -1.29873629, -0.42121177,  2.32836506])
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that looks like what I was after.